# Insert posted data in SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, http-post

I am able to post the data from Excel to ASP.NET MVC web service. Here is My code for that:

```
Sub SendData()
Dim HttpReq As Object, url As String
Set HttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
url = "http://localhost:11121/Student/PostData/"
HttpReq.Open "POST", url, False
HttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
HttpReq.Send "Student=jsmith112"
Debug.Print HttpReq.ResponseText
End Sub
```

Now, I Want to have a ControllerAction "Insert" That will Insert this posted data in SQLServer Database.

What do I need to do to controller action for this?

Comment: I am currently debating helping you, what have you tried so far?  Are you looking for how to do it using EF?  Or how to build a controller?

Comment: How to build a controller action to insert the posted data in DB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.POST)`> attribute if it's vs2008 or just `<HttpPost()>` for vs2010 to your controller method, so it receives the posted data.
Please note that this is in C#, syntax is slightly different for VB.

Comment: I have vs2010, Yes, I do have <HttpPost()> for my controller action. I am struggling with what o put inside my controller action.